# How to scan a QR code into bitcoinQT armory?

Tags: armory

im testing out bitcoinqt armory and was wondering how do i import a QR code paper wallet? there's no option to take a picture of my paper wallet. how can this be done easily?

Comment: Is there a private key written on the paper wallet? Import that through the options. **Don't tell us your private key aswell.**

Comment: yea i know that but what other way besides typing a case sensitive text?

Comment: You can try to convert the string the QR is with some program and copy and paste.

Comment: sorry i can't right click on a physical piece of paper and have a popup and select copy. =(

Comment: http://webqr.com/